# No Row Available Exception

Tags: jsf, richfaces

When I try to click on the same page twice, I get No Row Available Exception.
And below is the stack trace.

> javax.faces.model.NoRowAvailableException at
>   javax.faces.model.ListDataModel.getRowData(ListDataModel.java:150) at
>   org.ajax4jsf.model.SequenceDataModel.getRowData(SequenceDataModel.java:147)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.model.ModifiableModel$RowKeyWrapperFactory.wrapObject(ModifiableModel.java:75)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ObjectWrapperFactory$2.convert(ObjectWrapperFactory.java:190)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ObjectWrapperFactory.convertList(ObjectWrapperFactory.java:151)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.model.impl.expressive.ObjectWrapperFactory.wrapList(ObjectWrapperFactory.java:188)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.model.ModifiableModel.filter(ModifiableModel.java:252)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.model.ModifiableModel.modify(ModifiableModel.java:240)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable.createDataModel(UIDataTable.java:140)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:621)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.setRowKey(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:339)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractTableRenderer.encodeTableStructure(AbstractTableRenderer.java:138)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.renderkit.html.DataTableRenderer.doEncodeBegin(DataTableRenderer.java:140)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.renderkit.html.DataTableRenderer.doEncodeBegin(DataTableRenderer.java:128)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeBegin(RendererBase.java:100)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:823)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:937) at
>   org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptorBase.encodeBegin(UIDataAdaptorBase.java:1225)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:275)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.html.AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.encodeChildren(AjaxOutputPanelRenderer.java:78)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:279)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:200)
>   at
>   org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PanelRenderer.java:195)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:287)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
>   at
>   com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:592)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
>   at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>   at
>   org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>   at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   com.alcandor.alc.servlet.filter.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:106)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Can anyone tell me the root cause for this issue..

Comment: Where yo clicked in the page ? any button? Any row from Datatable or somewhere else? You did not mentioned anything .Also you didn't add any code How someone will able to help yo.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi- Sorry for providing insufficient information.. I clicked on the menu ie BreadCrumb